# Filter table on attribute of first result from joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two tables `users` and `task_lists`, `users` has_many `task_lists`.

`task_lists` belongs to `users` and has an attribute `tasks_counter`.

users

**|id|**

task_lists

**|id|user_id|tasks_counter|**

I would like to find all the `users` whose **first** (MIN(id)) `tasks_list` has a `tasks_counter` < 5.

How would I achieve this in PostGreSQL? I'm using Rails, if somebody knows a solution using ActiveRecords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set `users_ids` variable with an `Array` containing all `User` id's whose first `TaskList` has a `tasks_counter` < 5:

```rb
user_ids = TaskList.select("MIN(id) AS id, user_id, tasks_counter")
                   .group(:user_id)                                  # Get first TaskList for each user
                   .select { |t| t.tasks_counter < 5 }               # Keep users tha meet criteria
                   .pluck(:user_id)                                  # Return users' id in array
```

If you would like to get an `ActiveRecord_Relation` object with `User` objects you can use the result from the previous query and filter `User`.

```rb
users = User.where(id: user_ids)
```

Or, everything in one line:

```rb
users = User.where(id: TaskList.select("MIN(id) AS id, user_id, tasks_counter")
                               .group(:user_id)
                               .select { |t| t.tasks_counter < 5 }
                               .pluck(:user_id))
```

Comment: Hi Gerry, when I try this in PostGreSQL: `TaskList.select("MIN(id) AS id, user_id").group(:user_id).having("tasks_counter <1")` I get an error message:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "task_lists.tasks_counter" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. Do you know how to deal with this?

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be better to use `pluck(:user_id)` instead of `map(&:user_id)`?

Comment: Ohh, you're right; you can't add it neither `group` or `select` because then it won't get the correct data. But we on only need that to use `having` to filter user that do not meet `tasks_counter < 5`, so we can do that with select. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Randomtheories Yes, pluck should be better but i had a strange behavior using it, so provided an alternative (map) solution. But with updated solution it should work fine. Check it out.